# EncrpytElement class is empty

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encryption

I am trying to us C# to create an encrypted XML file. I am folling this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746(v=vs.110).aspx

I have included a reference to system.security.dll and I have included the namespaces System.Xml, System.Security.Cryptography, and System.Security.Cryptography.Xml as the examples says.

However the example does not compile. It seems EncryptedXml class is recognized but on the second line below I get this error: "'EncryptedXml' does not contain a definition for 'EncryptData' and no extension method 'EncryptData' accepting a first argument of type 'EncryptedXml' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
...
EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();
byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, false);
...
```

I am probably missing something simple. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: I closed and opened Visual Studio and now it works...  Thanks for the help.

Comment: what type are elementToEncrypt and sessionKey?

Comment: I closed and reopen Visual Studio and now it works...

Answer (score 0):

`elementToEncrypt` is of a wrong type per error, verify that it's `XmlElement`

*`public byte[] EncryptData(XmlElement inputElement, SymmetricAlgorithm symmetricAlgorithm, bool content)`*